# Printing the elements of a forward linked list

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I'm a sophomore in computer science who's working on a linked list class for his DSA class. I believe this code can be improved, but I'm not sure how because everything got really messy really fast. Thanks.

List.hpp:

```
// This is a blueprint for all list-like data structures.
// It won't specify how the operations are carried out.
#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List()
    {}

    virtual ~List()
    {}

    List(const List&)
    {}

    virtual void insert(int pos, const T& item) = 0;
    virtual void append(const T& item) = 0;

    virtual T remove(const int pos) = 0;

    virtual int size() const = 0;

    virtual T& operator[](const int pos) = 0;
    // The const overload is called only when used on const object.
    virtual const T& operator[](const int pos) const = 0;

};
#endif // LIST_HPP
```

LinkedList.hpp:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKEDLIST_HPP

#include "List.hpp"
#include "Node.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class LinkedList: public List<T>
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_head{nullptr};
    Node<T>* m_tail{nullptr};

    int m_size{};

public:
    LinkedList() = default;

    LinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> i_list)
    {
        for (const auto& item : i_list)
        {
            append(item);
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        // Start from the beginning.
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // Traverse the list while deleting previous elements.
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next; // Move forward.
            delete m_head;     // Delete the previous element.
            m_head = temp;     // m_head moved one forward.
        }
    }

    auto head() const
    {
        return m_head;
    }

    auto tail() const
    {
        return m_tail;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    void prepend(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node holding our item and pointing to the head.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{item, m_head};

        // If the head is the last element
        // (meaning it is the only element),
        // it'll be the tail.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            m_tail = m_head;
        }

        m_head = new_item;
        m_size++;
    }

    void append(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node with no pointer.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{item};

        if (m_tail == nullptr)
        {
            // If the list is empty, set the new item as the head as well.
            m_head = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, update the current tail's next pointer to the new item and move the tail.
            m_tail->next = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }

        m_size++;
    }

    void insert(const int pos, const T& item)
    {

        // If the position is the beginning of the list, prepend the new node.
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            prepend(item);
        }
        // If the position is beyond the end of the list, append the new node.
        else if (pos >= m_size)
        {
            append(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new node.
            auto new_item = new Node<T>{item};

            // Starting from the head, go to the one previous position.
            auto temp = m_head;

            int i{};
            for (; i < pos - 1; ++i)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            new_item = temp->next;
            temp->next->next = new_item->next;

            m_size++;
        }
    }

    void remove_front()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        if (temp != nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_head = m_head->next; // Move m_head one element forward.
        delete temp;           // Get rid of the previous element.

        --m_size;
    }

    void remove_back()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        if (temp == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the list's size is 1.
        if (temp == m_tail)
        {
            delete temp;
            m_head = m_tail = nullptr;

            --m_size;

            return;
        }

        // Traverse to one past the end.
        while (temp->next != m_tail)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        m_tail = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete temp;

        m_tail->next = nullptr;

        --m_size;
    }

    T remove(const int pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        int i{};
        for (; i < pos - 1; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        auto to_removed = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp->next->next;

        T removed_data = to_removed->data; // Retrieve the data before deleting the node.

        delete to_removed;
        return removed_data;
    }

    T& operator[](const int pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        int i{};
        for (; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }

    const T& operator[](const int pos) const
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        int i{};
        for (; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    for (auto begin = list.head(); begin != nullptr; begin = begin->next)
    {
        os << begin->data << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

#endif // LINKEDLIST_HPP
```

main.cpp:

````
#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> l{1,2,4};

    for (int i{}; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        l.append(i * i);
    }
    std::cout << l << "\n";
}
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not too bad, so I think you're well on your way to mastering C++.  Here are a few things to consider.

### Be wary of signed versus unsigned

What happens if you specify a negative number for the position?  For example, `l.remove(-9);`?  I think you'll find that nothing good will happen there.  The two options you have are to check for and reject negative numbers or to declare it as `unsigned` to avoid the issue entirely.

### Use only necessary `#include`s

The `#include <cassert>` line in `list.hpp` is not necessary and can be safely removed.

### Consider returning `std::size_t` for `size()`

The standard containers tend to use `std::size_t` for the return type for `size()` and that is probably a good choice for your code, too.

### Consider range checking

Both of your `operator[]` return a reference and do no range checking, so that if one asks for `l[99]` the code will invoke undefined behavior.  This isn't necessarily a problem (the standard containers to the same thing) but you might consider documenting this fact and/or implementing an `at()` function that does bounds checking, as the standard containers do.

### Minimize the scope of variables

In a few places, you have something like this:

```
        int i{};
        for (; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
```

That's not wrong, but I think I would write it like this instead:

```
    for (int i{0}; i != pos; ++i) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

In that version, the scope of `i` is solely within the `for` loop.  Another idiomatic option is this:

```
    for ( ; pos; --pos) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

### Make sure your comments don't mislead

There is a comment in `remove_back()` that seems misleading to me.

```
        // Traverse to one past the end.
        while (temp->next != m_tail)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
```

In fact, it's traversing to one *before* the end.

### Consider slightly streamlining the code

In a few places, there are extra assignments that aren't needed.  For example, in `remove_back` we have this:

```
        m_tail = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete temp;

        m_tail->next = nullptr;
```

A slightly simpler version is this:

```
        m_tail = temp;
        delete m_tail->next;
        m_tail->next = nullptr;
```

### Reconsider the use of `const` arguments

The arguments for `operator[]` and `remove()` take `const int` arguments for the `pos` argument, but there's really no need for restricting the caller in this way since we're passing by value anyway.

### Use `override` or `final` on overridden functions

Explicitly using either `final` or `override` can help detect errors, and so you should use these where appropriate.  See [C.128](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-override) for details.

### Fix the bug

The `prepend()` function contains this code:

```
        // If the head is the last element
        // (meaning it is the only element),
        // it'll be the tail.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            m_tail = m_head;
        }
```

I think that if you think about this, you'll see that it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. About const arguments, I was reading about const correctness, I thought that would be good practice. Also thanks for other suggestions, I might not have paid attention because sometimes I was exhausted.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The OP is clearly violating **rule 0/3/5**; that means he is going to face **double-free**, **use-after-free**, and **memory-leak** as a consequence. The answer doesn't even bother to introduce `std::list` and `std::forward_list` as the primary solution, to prevent unnecessary efforts.

Comment: Certainly one would use `std::list` or some other standard data structure for production code.  However this question was marked "beginner" so the assumption is that the desire is to learn how to write a linked list rather than simply using one.